# Proving linear dependence in two directions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove the below statement but with no success, I hope someone here can offer me some help:

Let  $v_1,...,v_n $ be a linealry independent system of the $\mathbb K $ vector space *V* and u = $ \lambda_1v_1 + ...+ \lambda_nv_n $ with $ \lambda_1,..,\lambda_n \in \mathbb K. $ Show that the system $v_1-u,..,v_n-u$ is linealry dependent if and only if $ \lambda_1 +...+ \lambda_n = 1$.

My idea was to to sort of end up with a linear equation then solve, but I didn'T get too far with this. I mean something like :

$v_1 - u$ = $v_1 - \lambda_1 v_1$

$v_2 - u$ = $v_2 - \lambda_1 v_1 +\lambda_2 v_2 $ and so on until *n*

I thought of then of then using the definition of linear depence and solving the homogenous system so :

$v_1 - \lambda_1 v_1$ = 0

$v_2 - \lambda_1 v_1 +\lambda_2 v_2 $ = 0

I did not get too far with this approach and would be more than grateful for any suggestions on how to go about this prrof.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually somewhat sneaky. One direction isn't bad. Suppose $\sum \lambda_i = 1$. Then
$$\sum_i \lambda_i(v_i-u) = \sum_i \lambda_iv_i - \big(\sum_i\lambda_i\big)u = \big(\sum_i\lambda_iv_i\big) - u = 0,$$
so we have a nontrivial linear relation among the vectors $v_i-u$ (note that at least one $\lambda_i$ must be nonzero!).

For the converse, suppose $\sum\lambda_i\ne 1$, and consider a linear combination
$$\sum_i c_i(v_i-u) = \sum_i c_i\big(v_i-\sum_j\lambda_jv_j\big) = 0.$$ We want to show that all the $c_i=0$. Rewriting this, we have (relabeling indices at the second point)
$$0=\sum_i c_iv_i - \sum_i c_i\sum_j\lambda_jv_j = \sum_i c_iv_i - \sum_k c_k\sum_i\lambda_iv_i = \sum_i\big(c_i-\big(\sum_k c_k\big)\lambda_i\big)v_i.$$
Now, how can this happen? Because we are told that the $v_i$ form a linearly independent set, we must have 
$$
c_i -\big(\sum\limits_k c_k\big)\lambda_i=0 \quad\text{for all }i. \qquad (\star)
$$
Sum this over $i$ and you get
$$\sum_i c_i = \sum_kc_k\sum_i\lambda_i.$$
Since $\sum\lambda_i\ne 1$, we conclude that $\sum c_i = 0$, and, by ($\star$), therefore $c_i=0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $u-v_i$'s are linearly independent iff the determinant

$$\det_{\mathcal B}(u-v_1,\cdots,u-v_n)=\begin{vmatrix}\lambda_1-1&\lambda_1&\cdots&\lambda_1
\\\lambda_2&\lambda_2-1&\cdots&\lambda_2
\\\vdots &&\vdots&
\\\lambda_n&\lambda_n&\vdots&\lambda_n-1
\end{vmatrix}\ne0$$
where $\mathcal B=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$ is the basis of $\operatorname{span}(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$.

Now add all the rows  to the first one and subtract all the columns with the first one we find a lower triangular matrix with determinant $(-1)^{n-1}\sum_i\lambda_i$. So we conclude that the given vectors are linearly independent iff $\sum_i\lambda_i\ne1$.